# Who was the US first cross-dressing governor?

Tags: united-states, political-history

Who was the US first cross-dressing governor?

Comment: Are you sure it was a president? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Edgar_Hoover#Cross-dressing_story

Comment: The first? So, it's a custom or a tradition? Do you know more presidents who cross-dress?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10ff6TvjLFE was the video I was thinking of I misremembered he was the first crossdressing governor not president.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Hyde,_3rd_Earl_of_Clarendon#Cross-Dressing

Comment: Then you should change the title, and update the question!

Comment: I don't have the ability to watch video right now - does the video provide the answer? Can you summarize the video content ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [Edward Hyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Hyde,_3rd_Earl_of_Clarendon), later the 3rd Earl of Clarendon, who was the British governor of the colonies of New York and New Jersey, 1701-1708, decades before the USA because independent. He's famous for [cross-dressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Hyde,_3rd_Earl_of_Clarendon#Cross-Dressing), among fans of ludicrous history.

However, the US office of governor seems to descend fairly directly from that of the British colonial governors, so he's probably the man who that video is talking about (I gave up after a few seconds, it's too hard on my eyes).